# Cmake not detecting boost-python when installing ROS

Tags: python, boost, cmake, ros, boost-python

I have been trying to install ROS on my Mac and have gotten around the errors with different libraries depending on different versions of boost.

However, it seems that one library is not even detecting boost-python.

Here is the error I get:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2048 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.67.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_python

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- skipping nosetests(parser.py) in project 'camera_calibration_parsers'
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'camera_calibration_parsers': 
  Command '['/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/src/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST', '-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers && /Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/src/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

This is what happens when I run it with -DBoost_DEBUG=ON

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'camera_calibration_parsers'
==> Building with env: '/Users/nik312123/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /Users/nik312123/ros_catkin_ws/src/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/nik312123/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/nik312123/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -G Unix Makefiles in '/Users/nik312123/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers'
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated;/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.11.2/
-- This workspace overlays: /Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/python
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- nosetests not found, Python tests can not be run (try installing package 'python-nose')
-- catkin 0.7.14
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1125 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1127 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1133 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1135 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1203 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1205 ]   BOOST_ROOT = 
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1207 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1209 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1211 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1310 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1334 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.67.0
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1420 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = 
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1430 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1506 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1508 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1571 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1760 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-mt-1_67;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/local/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1813 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_67;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/local/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1760 ] Searching for PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_python-mt-1_67;boost_python-mt;boost_python
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/local/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1813 ] Searching for PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_python-mt-d-1_67;boost_python-mt-d;boost_python-mt;boost_python
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/local/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1760 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-mt-1_67;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = /usr/local/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1813 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-mt-d-1_67;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:400 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = /usr/local/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = /usr/local/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1887 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2048 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.67.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_python

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- skipping nosetests(parser.py) in project 'camera_calibration_parsers'
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/redacted/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I tried options such as using -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON and exporting several paths like below:

```
export INCLUDE="/usr/local/include/boost:$INCLUDE"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

I also have the CMakeOutput.log as mentioned at the end of the -DBoost_DEBUG=ON code block. It is very long, so [I made a pastebin for it here.](https://pastebin.com/0FDge4wV)

Comment: With option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` messages about searching Boost will be much more informative. Such way you can find which **exact** filename(s), corresponded to `boost_python` library, is searched and where. Then compare these filenames and directories with ones you actually have.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry! The error with -DBoost_DEBUG=ON was mixed with the log without.

Comment: Well, the line `Searching for PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_python-mt-1_67;boost_python-mt;boost_python` contains files which a searched as `boost-bython` library. Do you have one of these files (under `/usr/local/lib`)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have libboost_python27-mt.a, libboost_python27-mt.dylib, libboost_python27.a, and libboost_python27.dylib in /usr/local/lib

Comment: Very similar problem (but not resolved yet): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919160/cmake-not-finding-boost-python-lib-with-brew-macos.

Comment: @Tsyvarev He seems to say it was resolved by changing COMPONENTS to python27. How does that work?

Comment: The referenced question is about the code which is **written by the asker**, so he may change the code (by replacing `python` with `python27`) for make it work. In your case, the code is **not yours**, so you shouldn't change it. (Well, you may change the code, but this is not the "right" way to fix the problem). But I see GigiBayte2 [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52574402/3440745) the resolution without changing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer based on Tsyvarev's link. You can symlink the libraries in the same directory without the appended 27 like so:

```
ln -s libboost_python27-mt.a libboost_python-mt.a
ln -s libboost_python27-mt.dylib libboost_python-mt.dylib
ln -s libboost_python27.a libboost_python.a
ln -s libboost_python27.dylib libboost_python.dylib
```

Comment: This was just what I needed! Thanks @Tsyvarev for the inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

You've got Boost installed, but have you built the Boost binaries? See

[unix-prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary)

Many Boost libraries are header-only and don't require building a binary, but boost-python does. See this answer for a list of libraries that do require building:

[Which Boost libraries are header-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13604163/9816902)

Comment: I'll try this and let you know how it goes. Just to let you know, I already have boost and boost-python individually installed through homebrew. (brew install boost and brew install boost-python)