# OpenNERO windows: Could not find the following Boost libraries: boost_python

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake, boost-python

I am trying to run [OpenNERO](https://github.com/nnrg/opennero) on my Windows 10. I had installed all the dependencies mentioned on their wiki for building it. My Python version is 2.7.15 
(have tried with Python 2.7, and latest 3.7.1 as well), boost version is 1.58  (have tried 1.66 and 1.53 as well).

I went to my boost folder location: "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0", and opened the command prompt as an administrator in that location, and then followed the [instructions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) to build boost.
I ran the `bootstrap.bat` file in the cmd, output shown below:
[image]

Then I ran the `.\b2 --build-type=complete -j2` command which ran for a couple of hours and the short output is shown in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/X2tVTztk).

Following this I went to Cmake and tried to build the project which gave me following errors:

> Could NOT find Boost
>
> Boost version: 1.67.0
>
> Boost include path: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_67_0
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>     boost_python
> ```
>
> Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found. You may
>   need to install these additional Boost libraries. Alternatively, set
>   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or
>   BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
>
> CMake Error at source/CMakeLists.txt:33 (MESSAGE):
>
> Boost libraries were not found, please install from
>   http://www.boost.org/

I have all the boost-python files in my stage/libs folder as shown below then why is it giving me this error?

[image]
My environment variables are also correctly set-up as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Because some people are hostile to Windows. They just don't test their code on Windows.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: That messes about searching `boost_python` with `find_package`... Now it is explicitely [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) that component name should be `python27` or `python36`, but so much code still uses just `python`. See also questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566234/cmake-not-detecting-boost-python-when-installing-ros or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842069/finding-boost-python3-with-anaconda-cmake-prefix. (Or any other question which has both [tag:cmake] and [tag:boost-python] tags.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev So I tried creating a copy of all these files with the 27 removed, for example, i duplicated `boost_python27-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib` and renamed the dupe as `boost_python-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib` so that both the files with python27 and python exist, but it still gave the same error :(

Comment: I tried using Python, Python2, Python2.7, Python27, and none of them seems to have worked.

Comment: it appears that cmake is looking for filenames of the format "boost_python-vc141-mt-x32-1_67" while my file names are of the format "boost_python27-vc141-mt-x64-1_67", so may be i should install 32 bit version of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the line 26 in [this cmake file](https://github.com/nnrg/opennero/blob/master/source/CMakeLists.txt) from `FIND_PACKAGE (Boost COMPONENTS python filesystem serialization system date_time)` to `FIND_PACKAGE (Boost COMPONENTS python27 filesystem serialization system date_time)` so that it looks for python27 instead of python. Also used the 64bit generator in cmake gui instead of the 32 bit one.

[image]